# Extension Methods With View Bounds Dependent On Extended Object

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm trying to define some extension methods for a class as shown below.  One of the methods needs to accept an argument that is convertible to a path-dependent type that includes the extended object in its path.  Unfortunately, compilation fails at the call-site because the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that the reference to 'outer' in the view boudns definition refers to the same object as 'outer' at the call site.  Is there a way to fix this so that the commented line compiles?

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Outer {
  class Inner {
  }

  class ConvertsToInner {
  }

  object ConvertsToInner {
    implicit def convert(source : ConvertsToInner) = new Inner()
  }
}

class Code {
  implicit class ExtendsOuter(val outer : Outer) {
    def extensionMethod[T <% outer.Inner](argument : T) { }
  }

  val outer = new Outer()
  val convertsToInner = new outer.ConvertsToInner()

  //does not compile!
  outer.extensionMethod(convertsToInner)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace extension method definition from:

```
def extensionMethod[T <% outer.Inner](argument : T) { }
```

to

```
def extensionMethod[T <% Outer#Inner](argument : T) { }
```

Comment: Actually, in this case, it needs to be outer.Inner.